# how to check html <object> data loaded completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I have a html object element as follows

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="http://dom.example.com/t"></object>
```

i need to check whether the object tag data is loaded completely with jQuery

`tried $(document).ready(function()..`  wont work

> Note :  http://dom.example.com/t , the data is loading with some
>   delay ~~ 10ms , no domain issues persists

Comment: Did you you try $(".myobject").load(function()...?

Comment: @undefined , please issue a solution